# ES Modules in a Next.js server.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, es6-modules

I checked a few examples from the `Next.js` repository

- https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/custom-server-express
- https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/custom-server-koa

and noticed that examples use ES Modules in React components and CommonJS modules in the `server.js` file. 
I'd like to keep my code written in one style, is it possible to use only ES Modules in a `Next.js` project?

Answer (score 1):

This is sitting as a feature request in the Next.js backlog.
https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/9607